# Parsing of XML fails under Grizzly using JAX-RS on a chunked POST

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, apache-httpclient-4.x, grizzly

I have encountered a problem when using Apache HttpClient 4.3.6 to POST XML to Grizzly under Jersey 2.15.  I switched to use the Apache HttpClient last night so I could introduce support for chunked POST operations and support for 100-Continue (for reasons I will not get into).  The message flow seems to be correct, but when it comes to JAX-RS annotated servlet to be invoked I get the "Content is not allowed in prolog." error on entry.  Here is the method signature:

```
@POST
@Path("/callback")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, NsiConstants.NSI_DDS_V1_XML })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, NsiConstants.NSI_DDS_V1_XML })
public Response notification(NotificationListType notify) {
   …
}
```

Before introducing the Apache HttpClient with the chunked POST and 100-continue this worked fine.  I changed the input parameter to be of type String and discovered the start of the data stream contains "800\r\n" followed by the complete XML.  The "800\r\n" happens to be the first chunk length.  There are multiple chunks but only the first chunk length is in the stream.  If I manually remove this I can parse the XML without issue, but would rather not have to do this.  Can anyone provide guidance?

Here is a debug trace of the initial interaction:

```
2015-01-27 13:00:51,879 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:124) - http-outgoing-3 >> POST /dds/callback HTTP/1.1
2015-01-27 13:00:51,879 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Accept: application/xml
2015-01-27 13:00:51,879 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Content-Type: application/xml
2015-01-27 13:00:51,879 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> User-Agent: Jersey/2.15 (Apache HttpClient 4.3.6)
2015-01-27 13:00:51,880 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2015-01-27 13:00:51,880 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Host: localhost:8402
2015-01-27 13:00:51,880 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2015-01-27 13:00:51,880 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Expect: 100-continue
2015-01-27 13:00:51,881 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:127) - http-outgoing-3 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2015-01-27 13:00:51,881 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "POST /dds/callback HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,881 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept: application/xml[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,881 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Content-Type: application/xml[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,882 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "User-Agent: Jersey/2.15 (Apache HttpClient 4.3.6)[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,882 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,882 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Host: localhost:8402[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,882 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,883 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Expect: 100-continue[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,883 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,883 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,884 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 << "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,885 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 << "[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,886 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:113) - http-outgoing-3 << HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
2015-01-27 13:00:51,945 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "800[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,945 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"

…

2015-01-27 13:00:51,968 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "0[\r][\n]"
2015-01-27 13:00:51,968 DEBUG (org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire:72) - http-outgoing-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it, can you pls. create a testcase on github?

Comment: I created a simple test case [here](https://github.com/jmacauley/jersey-post-test) that demonstrates the issue.  Please let me know if I have done something wrong that is causing it.

Comment: Thank you. I've created an issue, it will be fixed in the next Grizzly release. https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1742